# Angular 9 + ngrx testing in general

Tags: angular, ngrx

If you start new project based on Angular 9 and ngrx, what frontend tests would you write?

From a developer point of view: the more the better.
From a business point of view: not really?

The project doesn´t have unlimited money to spend, but it should be spent wisely. So the question is simple and I would like to hear opinions like:

1) I would write only e2e tests and not tests from @angular/core/testing, it is the most wise decision, because compared to the situation that the developers are in pressure and e2e tests everything.

2) I would write e2e tests only as smoke tests to test basic functionality, because it is time consuming to write more, more e2e tests are easily broken, longer to execute and so on. And I would also write shallow integration tests for components.

3) I would write tests for everything because why not. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We cover every component / service with unit tests, environment and dependencies are fully mocked (we use ng-mocks for that), only a current class / template isn't mocked.
And we have very simple e2e tests which check public endpoints (just to be sure built they aren't broken) no post requests, just navigation and assertion that content matches expected defaults.

Lack of e2e tests is caused by amount of available time :) no time to write them!